# reducing dimension of an icon with Preview

Tags: mac

I had an png icon file of dimension 40*40 with a size of 2 KB. I adjust its dimensions with Preview app to get 25*25. I got the icon file converted to 25*25, but now its size is 3 KB. Why? As we reduce dimension, the size must get reduce. But it is not happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all PNG files are created equal. Two pixel identical PNG files can be different file sizes.

## Time vs CPU

The size of the file depends greatly on the amount of processing time spent during its creation.

An application like Preview.app is quick to save but creates larger PNG files.

At the other end of the spectrum, a free tool like [ImageOptim.app](https://imageoptim.com) will spend minutes on larger PNG files trying a wide range of parameters searching for the smallest PNG file.

Many web developers and graphic artists use tools like ImageOptim to post-process their artwork before it is distributed.

> ## ImageOptim
>
> [image]
>
> ImageOptim is a free app that makes images take up less disk space and load faster, without sacrificing quality. It optimizes compression parameters, removes junk metadata and unnecessary color profiles.
>
> ImageOptim seamlessly integrates the best optimization tools: PNGOUT, Zopfli, Pngcrush, AdvPNG, extended OptiPNG, JpegOptim, jpegrescan, jpegtran, and Gifsicle.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple algorithm to optimize the size of PNG files.
**Preview** is known to not be not optimal on that point.

If you want to optimize the size of your PNG, there are multiple tools available on the web.

Just by randomly searching on google :

- https://pngquant.org/
- https://imageoptim.com/
- http://www.gingerbeardman.com/pngenie/